# UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to open a com port in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am using an Arduino Board to write on the Serial COM port, and using a C# app to read it. But whenever I try to run the C# program, an exception (UnauthorizedAccessException) occurs when it tries to open a serial port. How do I properly open a serial port?

I have very little knowledge in C++. Most of my knowledge comes from their similarities with C++, and a lot of googling tutorials. Here is one of the codes that I copied from one of the tutorials I found:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";

            serialPort1.Open();

            richTextBox1.Text = "opened";
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            string text = richTextBox1.Text;
            serialPort1.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UnauthorizedAccessException often indicates that port is already open somewhere. Do you perhaps have open SerialMonitor in ArduinoIDE or another software that can access SerialPort? Also please, post actual code that you have used, not some example from network - this one is missing creation of `new SerialPort()`

Comment: I don't know where the Serial Port is created. I just used the design view in Visual Studio to drag and drop the serial element.
Also, I've tried to run it while the Serial Monitor was closed. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, it MIGHT be the Serial Monitor causing the problem. I'm checking it thoroughly right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that you have COM3 already open in another application (See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open(v=vs.110).aspx)). When you click on button1 the program can see that the COM port is open (in another application) and tries to write to it, even though your program does not have access to it.

Firstly you will need to create an instance of the serial port (which I suspect you have already done since you would receive different error). I create my instance when Form1 is created:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create an instance of a serial port
        serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
    }
```

In the following I have renamed button2 to openPortButton:

```
    private void openPortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

You could make your program aggressive by closing the serial port if it is already open:

```
        // Check if the serial port is already open. If it is close it down first.
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }
```

You can also catch any exceptions when opening the serial port by wrapping it inside a try-catch statement:

```
        if(!serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";

            try
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                // Add exception handling here
            }
        }
```

Then test that the serial port is actually open:

```
        // Test connection
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "opened";
            commsEstablished = true;
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "not successful";
            commsEstablished = false;
        }
    }
```

Where `commsEstablished` is a private bool in Form1.

Now when the send button is pressed test the `commsEstablished` variable: (I have also renamed button1 to sendButton)

```
    private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(commsEstablished && serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            string text = richTextBox1.Text;
            try
            {
                serialPort1.WriteLine(text);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Add exception handling here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Theorettically you are right, but... we for example have the case that we closed a port, then check for IsOpen ... open it  - and guess what - the exception is there. After closing and some wait it can be reopened....

Comment: @Offler, That is good to know. Can you provide us an indication of how long you have to wait before opening the com port?

Comment: seems to depend on hardware and what the sytem is doing in the moment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348580/serialport-unauthorizedaccessexception suggests over 300 ms, we have ~250 as with 200 it sometimes failed, and with 250 ms it did not fail for a few years.