# Unable to access/open u-blox virtual COM port in order to retrieve data from the u-blox GPS sensor which is built in a window10 tablet

Tags: c#, nmea

I have wrote a C# WPF program to retrieve the NMEA data from the u-blox 6 gps location sensor which is built in a Win10 tablet. However when the program trying to access/open the u-blox virtual COM port, ArgumentException is thrown, how to resolve this problem, Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to open a com port in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487061/unauthorizedaccessexception-when-trying-to-open-a-com-port-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I have read it and i my code is similar to the solution but still it doesn't work,if i access the u-blox virtual com port through uCenter either through the Port or through the Sensor API, the data can be retrieve by the uCenter.